# Where can I download PostgreSQL 8.2.16 installer for OSX?

Tags: macos, postgresql, installation, download

I've been searching for about an hour, but could not find any installer for this version...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Homebrew for OSX, and have been really happy with it.  After you install it, you can

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

and get a clean installation of postgres.  However, it doesn't install any gui tools, just psql.

http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/homebrew-os-xs-missing-package-manager/

EDIT:

Apologies, I think the `brew` formula is building 8.4.3 right now, but it shouldn't be too hard to edit it to use the version you require...

EDIT #2:

You might be able to find the version you want here:
http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus/getinstaller.do

Comment: No problem, glad to hear you found a solution!